# Why doesn't the emulator behave correctly on orientation change?

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

As far as I know, by default, when device is rotated, the current activity is destroyed and recreated. I'm rotating the emulator using LeftCTRL+F12 but it's not destroyed. I have logs in `OnDestroy`, `OnCreate` and `OnStart` and `OnResume`, but none of those fire up when I rotate the device.

Before:

[image: before the change]

After:

[image: after the change]

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.geo_quiz"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.geo_quiz.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your manifest file

Comment: it will be destroyed unless you handle configuration change yourself

Comment: @Raghunandan I don't remember handling configuration changes... Yet it doesn't get destroyed.

Comment: Given that the system status bar has not changed orientation, it looks to me like you have rotated the graphical output of the emulator, but not rotated its simulated accelerometers or its android platform's idea of orientation.  It's as if you turned your monitor sideways, rather than the device.  This seems like an emulator usage problem, not something with your app, and likely all apps on the emulator will behave the same way.

Comment: can you please post your on Destroy()

Comment: @Oleksiy then it will be destroyed and recreated. So nothing to worry

Comment: @ChrisStratton, yes I thought about it, it doesn't look like the device had been rotated... I wonder if I can fix that problem and test rotation on emulator

Comment: Seems like orientation is locked to Portrait mode somewhere.

Comment: it seems that the device was not changing orientation. Your activity still in portrait mode

Answer (score 7):

I think I know the answer. I have the same problem using the emulator for Pixel 2, API level 28, on Android Studio 3.4.1 (the latest as of writing this).

How I fixed this was by dragging the Quick Settings drop-down menu on the emulator (click and drag from the top right corner of the emulator's screen), and ensuring that auto-rotation was enabled.

When I checked, it wasn't, so I enabled it. After enabling it, the emulator worked normally :).

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 3):

Your emulated device, i.e., the phone, (not the emulator) may not have rotation detection turned on.  In the phone's settings, turn on rotation detection.  Here is a screenshot of what that icon looks like.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screen shots, it seems that the device was not changing orientation. Your activity still shows a portrait layout. THe only thing that changed is the orientation of the displayed window. When an orientation change happen, your text should be upright, in the screenshot their "up" points to the left.
Run it on a real device, and onDestroy will be called. 100% of the time. guaranteed

Edit following Oleksiy comments:

1. try numpad7 first and then CMD+f12.
2. Also make sure your ADT is up to date (not just your build tools) - you do that by Eclipse > Check for Updates.
3. If the above does not work, try to do this programmatically, so you can debug your code (which will work on a real device): call `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` in your onCreate
4. **You shouldn't be doing development with emulator. Its too slow and unreliable. Bunch of stuff won't work there. Work with your device connected. you'll save yourself trouble.**

   I also found this bugreport, which was tagged "unreproducable": http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17963

Comment: Thank you, I know it's a problem with emulator now. Do you know how to fix it? I created different emulator devices with different resolutions and settings, and it still doesn't actually rotate the device on Ctrl+F12.

Comment: @Oleksiy which OS are you using? which IDE?

Comment: @Oleksiy, I've seen that happen on emulators configured with older versions of the OS. Try creating an AVD targeting 4.0+

Comment: @Guy Windows 8 and ADT (Eclipse)

Comment: @oleksiy - (1) try numpad7 first and then CMD+f12. 
(2) Also make sure your ADT is up to date (not just your build tools) - you do that by Eclipse > Check for Updates.
if that does not work, to debug try changing orientation programatically:
(3) call setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); in your onCreate
(4) You shouldn't be doing development with emulator. Its too slow, unreliable. Work with your device connected. you'll save yourself trouble.

I also found this bugreport, which was tagged "unreproducable": https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17963

Answer (score 0):

Go to the camera app first, then run your application. The camera app automatically changes your view.